# Sassc-2.0.0 requires ruby version >= 2.3.3, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 2.3.0p0

Tags: ruby, version

When I type `bundle install`, I get this message error:

> sassc-2.0.0 requires ruby version >= 2.3.3, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 2.3.0p0.

But I clean up my computer and there is no more version 2.3.0p0.

Here is the result of `bundle env` :

### Environment

```
Bundler             1.17.2
  Platforms         ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby                2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path         /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby
  Config Dir        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/etc
RubyGems            3.0.1
  Gem Home          /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1
  Gem Path          /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1:/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@global
  User Path         /root/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  Bin Dir           /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin
Tools               
  Git               2.7.4
  RVM               1.29.7 (manual)
  rbenv             rbenv 0.4.0
  chruby            not installed
  rubygems-bundler  (1.4.5)
```

### Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2018-12-19
Git SHA           3fc4de72b
Released Version  false
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same issue :
[Trouble removing ruby 2.3.0p0 from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752666/trouble-removing-ruby-2-3-0p0-from-ubuntu)

There is still a file ruby2.3 in usr/bin.

Comment: Now when I run `bundle install`, I get this message : bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle : /usr/bin/ruby2.3 : bad interpreter: No such file or directory. But when I type `which ruby`, I get : /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby.